# How to create our own custom text view in Android?

Tags: android

How to create our own custom text view in Android? I want to set different colors for the textview font.

Comment: This seems kind of excessive for changing the text color. Is there a reason why `TextView.setTextColor(color)` isn't sufficient for your situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever you want:

```
public class SimpleTextView extends TextView
{
    private static int color=Color.RED;

    public SimpleTextView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        this.setTextColor(color)
    }

    public SimpleTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setTextColor(color)
    }

    public SimpleTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.setTextColor(color)
    }

    public static void setGlobalColor(int gcolor)
    {
        color=gcolor;
    }

}
```

So anytime you can change color of your TextViews globally.

Answer (score 3):

Like eldarerathis commented, it's a bit overkilled if you would create a custom TextView just for changing the text color.

Nonetheless, [here is a tutorial](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-custom-textview.html) on how to create a custom TextView.

[Building Custom component](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) on Android developer is also a good read, in fact, I'd encourage you to read through it first.

The summarize 3 steps:

> 1. Extend an existing View class or subclass with your own class.
> 2. Override some of the methods from the superclass. The superclass
>      methods to override start with 'on',
>      for example, onDraw(), onMeasure(),
>      and onKeyDown(). This is similar to
>      the on... events in Activity or
>      ListActivity that you override for
>      lifecycle and other functionality
>      hooks.
> 3. Use your new extension class. Once completed, your new extension
>      class can be used in place of the view
>      upon which it was based.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is set a text color you can use the [textColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3atextColor) attribute.

```
<TextView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="MyText"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
/>
```